# How to record audio headphones connected?

Tags: ios, record, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession, background-music

i want to record my voice and  music together which is playing background. Like a karaoke app. How can i do that when headphone connected. There are not any examples of how to  do this.

Comment: is there anything you've done so far? any code ?

Comment: If there aren't any examples you could just go ahead and *try it out*, do some research, do some coding, play around with the api - and eventually figure out a way doing it or realize that is not even possible.